# How to add float (*vertices)[3] to C#

Tags: c#, c

I need to convert C structure to C# structure.

In C:

```
 typedef struct Lib3dsMesh {
 //..
 float (*vertices)[3]; 
 //..
}
```

In C#:

```
     [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Lib3dsMesh
{
   ????
}
```

It's for using 3ds C library for my C# project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good support for constant sized inline arrays in .net (you could use the `fixed` keyword, but I generally avoid that). So I'd use a struct with 3 fields instead.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Vector3f
{
  public readonly float X,Y,Z;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct Lib3dsMesh {
  public Vector3f* vertices;
}
```